Error: Dart library 'dart:js_interop_unsafe' is not available on this platform for flutter web app
When i run

flutter build web --web-renderer html --release
--dart-define=flavor=stg

I get the following error
Target dart2js failed: Exception: ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pointycastle-3.8.0/lib/src/platform_check/node_crypto.dart:5:8:
Error: Dart library 'dart:js_interop_unsafe' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:js_interop_unsafe';

      ^
Info: The unavailable library 'dart:js_interop_unsafe' is imported through these packages:

    main.dart => package:grubops => package:excel => package:archive => package:pointycastle => dart:js_interop_unsafe
    ...

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

    main.dart => package:grubops/main.dart => package:...package:pointycastle/src/platform_check/platform_check.dart =>
    package:pointycastle/src/platform_check/web.dart => package:pointycastle/src/platform_check/node_crypto.dart => dart:js_interop_unsafe
    ...

../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pointycastle-3.8.0/lib/src/platform_check/node_crypto.dart:11:2:
Error: Undefined name 'staticInterop'.
@staticInterop
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pointycastle-3.8.0/lib/src/platform_check/node_crypto.dart:11:2:
Error: This can't be used as an annotation; an annotation should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant
constructor.
@staticInterop
 ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pointycastle-3.8.0/lib/src/platform_check/node_crypto.dart:15:19:
Error: The method 'callMethod' isn't defined for the class 'JSObject'.
 - 'JSObject' is from 'dart:_interceptors'.
    return crypto.callMethod('randomFillSync'.toJS, buf);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.

I tried clean building the app but nothing works out for me. Can i get some help for this please ? much appreciated.
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale en-LK)
• Flutter version 3.10.1 on channel stable at /Users/.../flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision d3d8effc68 (11 months ago), 2023-05-16 17:59:05 -0700
• Engine revision b4fb11214d
• Dart version 3.0.1
• DevTools version 2.23.1
the place mentioned in the error looks like this
/// Wrapper for needed NodeJS Crypto library function and require.
library nodecryto;

import 'dart:js_interop';
import 'dart:js_interop_unsafe';

@JS()
external JSObject require(String id);

@JS()
@staticInterop
class NodeCrypto {
  static JSAny randomFillSync(JSAny buf) {
    final crypto = require('crypto');
    return crypto.callMethod('randomFillSync'.toJS, buf);
  }
}


might be a problem with pointy castle plugin
https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/issues

Because you included some packages that use an old version of webview
Or maybe The issue is that : flutter run tries to build for other platform instead of web
more info :
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/146710
